# How do I hide certain labels on Huggingface inference?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am currently using my customized labels in a token classification model and have pushed the model to hub.
I am using the labels shown as below:

```
label_list = [“NORM”, “COMMA”, “PERIOD”, “QUEST_MARK”, “EXCLAMATION”]

label2id = 
{‘COMMA’: ‘1’,
‘EXCLAMATION’: ‘4’,
‘NORM’: ‘0’,
‘PERIOD’: ‘2’,
‘QUEST_MARK’: ‘3’}

id2label = 
{‘0’: ‘NORM’,
‘1’: ‘COMMA’,
‘2’: ‘PERIOD’,
‘3’: ‘QUEST_MARK’,
‘4’: ‘EXCLAMATION’}
```

Currently on inference API, it shows:
[image]

How may I hide the label of `“NORM”(id=0)` and make the inference only show `labels of id1-4 (“COMMA”, “PERIOD”, etc.)`?
Thank you!

Comment: please make your question clear, where do you want to do this? Do you just want to replace "NORM" with `id0` in the visualization?  add the code if possible.

Comment: Hi! I was wondering how I could hide "NORM" on the inference interface. For the screenshot provided, I want to show only "PERIOD" and hide "NORM". I am using the above "id2label" and "label2id" code.

Comment: Is reuploading your model an option?